# Split String into Array in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am getting the output as 0,1,2,3. I need this to be split into array

Comment: why the downvote? just answer the question if it's clearly answerable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var a:Array = s.split(",")
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Vinay's answer, here is a link to the documentation:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#split()